# How I can make a string counter in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to do a string counter in vb.net like if in integer.

Logical example:

```
$counter=A

loop

    print $counter;

    $counter +=1;

endloop
```

output: `A,B,C,D`

Thanks a lot everybody.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and properly explain what your problem is, what you expect to happen and what have you tried so far, it's also advised to show some code examples of what you've tried so far

Comment: would you kindly narrow tags to your actual programming language? Is it `c#`, `vb.net` or `vba`? In this latter case `visual-studio` tag wouldn't apply neither

Comment: Is in vb.net but if you know in c# or vba, I can convert for my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `char` type, though it is inconvenient, you can iterate an int to do so.

```
Dim charNum As Integer = 65
Your loop start code
    print Chr(charNum).ToString();
    charNum +=1
End loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But it will just return a letter when the char be a correct number. So, won't works.

Comment: In your example, you show that you want each letter output, so this does what you asked]

Comment: Be careful, `chr(1)` returns a space character, but `chr(65)` returns the character A

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after:

```
For Each letter As Char In "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Debug.Print(letter)
Next
```

This will output:

> A 
>   B 
>   C 
>   ...

Here is a screenshot of the code with the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in VBA

```
Sub main()
    Dim strng As String
    Dim counter As Long

    strng = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Do While counter < Len(strng)
        counter = counter + 1
        Debug.Print Mid(strng, counter, 1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

of course you can add more ending condition in `Do While counter < Len(strng)`

Comment: @RubenSIlva, did you get through it?

Comment: @RubenSilva, it'd be nice of you giving proper feedbacks to people trying at helping you. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to take the method you want :

```
 Const Letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
 Dim nbLettersToDispay As Integer = 5

 For i = 0 To Math.Min(nbLettersToDispay, Letters.Length)
   If i <> Math.Min(nbLettersToDispay, Letters.Length) Then
       Debug.Print(Letters(i))
   End If
 Next i
```

In my code, you will simply have to change the value of the variable `nbLettersToDispay`, which represents the number of letters to display

Answer (score 0):

This is a function will also perform well >26

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Do While i < 100
    i += 1
    Console.WriteLine(excelColumnToLetter(i))
Loop

Function excelColumnToLetter(ByVal iColumn As Integer)
    Dim sLetters As String = ""
    Dim iTemp As Integer = 0
    Do While iColumn
        iTemp = (iColumn Mod 26)
        If iTemp = 0 Then iTemp = 26
        sLetters = Chr(iTemp + 64) & sLetters
        iColumn = (iColumn - iTemp) / 26
    Loop
    Return sLetters
End Function
```